# How to hide and show div element by id in a WordPress page?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a number of `div` elements on my page. I want to hide them all except for when they are clicked. When clicked, they should show. I have followed a number of examples found on SO. However, I can't seem to get any of them to work on my wordpress page, without multiple clicks. What am i doing wrong.

FYI, the code below is placed exactly as seen, into a Wordpress page.

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<strong><a href="#"  onclick="toggle_visibility('list_one');">List One</a></strong>
<div id="list_one" style="display: none">
  <ul>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
    <li>Item Five</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<strong><a href="#"  onclick="toggle_visibility('list_two');">List Two</a></strong>
<div id="list_two" style="display: none">
  <ul>
    <li>Item Uno</li>
    <li>Item Dos</li>
    <li>Item Tre</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The code is working, it may a conflict with the WordPress code : https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/1hq2o5yz/

Comment: Shorter and more fluid and messy version: https://jsfiddle.net/omerowitz/xz2ojt6r/9/

Comment: thanks @ZakariaAcharki that seems to most likely be the case. There is nothing more than text on the page before I enter the code above, however, it must be the core code, template code, or installed plugins for the rest of the site

Comment: " I can't seem to get any of them to work on my wordpress page" are you talking about your own custom (PHP) page or simply using WP Editor to add you JS? If editor view your source on browser. From recollection the editor will mangle/remove any JS added. Not sure about new Gutenberg editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to hide all div tags on single click?
then you can try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#list_one,#list_two {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#C5C5C3 ;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="list_one">
<ul>
    <li>Item Uno</li>
    <li>Item Dos</li>
    <li>Item Tre</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="list_two">
<ul>
    <li>Item Uno</li>
    <li>Item Dos</li>
    <li>Item Tre</li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>

function myFunction() {

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].style.display === "none") {
    divs[i].style.display = "block";
  } else {
    divs[i].style.display = "none";
  }       
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

for single div try below javascript

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("list_one");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  e.style.display = e.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none';
}
```

However, as a previous commenter said, your code does actually work.

If you are using jQuery you could do:

```
$('#list_one').toggle();
```

Comment: Your js code is essentially the same thing. You refactored it to eliminate the long if statement. Other than that, you did nothing to solve the issue that I have with my code working in a wordpress page